# Distributing $n$ candies to 3 people with restriction

Tags: combinatorics

Thor, Captain America and Spiderman split $2001$ candies among themselves. Due to seniority
perks, Thor must get strictly more candies than Captain America, who must get strictly more
candies than Spiderman, who must get at least one candy. How many ways can this be done?

I don't know if stars and bars would be applicable here. I started by concluding that the maximum no. of candies that Spiderman could receive is $666$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I would start with Stars and Bars to get the total number, ignoring the order restriction.  Then use Inclusion Exclusion to remove those in which (at least) two people get the same number.  And then divide by $6$ to get the order you want.

Comment: I would use generating functions personally.  It will be the coefficient of $x^{2001}$ of the expansion of $(1+x^3+x^6+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)$

Answer (score 1):

For a more combinatoric approach, see lulu's comment. I just want to say something else.

Remove the same amount of candies from the three people until Spiderman gets nothing. The question will then become:

Distribute $2001 - 3k$ ($1\leq k \leq 666$) candies to two people such that one gets more than the other, and both gets at least a candy.

There are $\lceil k/2\rceil - 1$ ways to do this.

So the answer is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{666}\Big\lceil\frac{k}{2}\Big\rceil - 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{333}(3k-2) + \sum_{k=1}^{333}(3k-1) = 3\sum_{k=1}^{333}(2k-1) = 3\cdot 333^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you write the first few terms, you can notice the arithmetic progressions:
$$\begin{align}1|(2,1998),(3,1997),...,(999,1001) &\Rightarrow \color{red}{998}\\
2|(3,1996),(4,1995),...,(999,1000)&\Rightarrow \color{blue}{997}\\
3|(4,1994),(5,1993),...,(998,1000)&\Rightarrow \color{red}{995}\\
4|(5,1992),(6,1991),...,(998,999) &\Rightarrow \color{blue}{994}\\
5|(6,1990),(7,1989),...,(997,999) &\Rightarrow \color{red}{992}\\
\vdots\\
664|(665,672),...,(668,669)&\Rightarrow \color{blue}{4}\\
665|(666,670),(667,669)&\Rightarrow \color{red}{2}\\
666|(667,668)&\Rightarrow \color{blue}{1} \end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\color{red}{\frac{998-2}{3}+1=333}; \quad \color{blue}{\frac{997-1}{3}+1=333}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{333}[\color{red}{2+3(i-1)}+\color{blue}{1+3(i-1)}]=3\sum_{i=1}^{333}[2i-1]=3\cdot 333^2.$$